# Flea and comb are connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$$ X = \{(0,1)\} \cup \{ (x,0) : 0 < x \leq 1\} \cup \left\{\left(\frac{1}{n},y\right) : n \in \mathbb{N} , \; \; 0 \leq y \leq 1\right\} $$

Is $X$ connected? I want to show $X$ is connected but It is kind of hard. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you prove that $X\setminus\{(0,1)\}$ is connected? Then you can prove that generally, if $E$ is connected, and $E \subset B \subset \overline{E}$, then $B$ is connected. It's probably easier to prove it in the general version than for a specific example where the details muddy the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y = \{ (x,0) | 0 < x \leq 1\} \cup \{(\frac{1}{n},y) | n \in \mathbb{N} , \; \; 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$. It should be clear that $Y$ is connected since it is path connected (imagine a comb).

You have $X= \{(0,1) \} \cup Y$.

Suppose $X \subset U \cup V$ where $U,V$ are open and disjoint. Without loss of generality, $Y \subset U$ ($Y$ cannot intersect both, otherwise it would not be connected). Suppose $X \subset V$ (that is, $(0,1) \in V$). Since $V$ is open, it must contain an infinite number of the points $\{(\frac{1}{n},1) \}_n \subset Y$, which contradicts $U,V$ being disjoint. Hence $X \subset U$.

Hence $X$ must be connected.

**Addendum**: For those with masochistic tendencies:

To show that $Y$ is connected without using path connectedness, we use the same technique.

I need a little result first: Suppose $C_1,C_2$ are two connected sets and $C_1 \cap C_2 \neq \emptyset$. Then $C = C_1 \cup C_2$ is connected.

To see this, suppose $U,V$ are disjoint open sets such that $C \subset U \cup V$. 
Let $x \in C_1 \cap C_2$, and without loss of generality, $x \in U$. Since $ x\in C_1$, we must have $C_1 \subset U$ (otherwise this would contradict the connectedness of $C_1$). Similarly we must have $C_2 \subset U$, hence $C \subset U$, and so $C$ must be connected.

Back to $Y$:

I need some notation. Let $T_n = \{ \frac{1}{n} \} \times [0,1]$, $H=(0,1]\times \{0\}$. Clearly $Y = H \cup (\cup_n T_n)$ and $H \cap  T_n \neq \emptyset$ for all $n$.

As above, suppose $U,V$ are disjoint open sets such that $Y \subset U \cup V$. Without loss of generality, suppose $H \subset U$. Now pick one of the $T_n$, then since $T_n \cap H \neq \emptyset$, we must have $T_n \subset U$. Since this is true for all $n$, we have $T_n \subset U$ for all $n$ and hence $Y \subset U$. Hence $Y$ is connected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend. But, I would like to solve the problem without using path-connectedness. Do you think it would be helpful if we show union of connected sets is connected? then our problem is solved since $X$ is the union of 3 connected sets. What do you think? @copper.hat

Comment: @Peruano: I have added some detail showing that $Y$ is connected without explicitly relying on path connectedness.

Comment: @Peruano: It is not true. **Every** set is the union of connected sets. $S = \cup_{x \in S} \{ x \}$.