# Show that the "Flea and Comb" space is connected

Tags: general-topology

Show that the "flea and comb" space defined as $X = \{(0, 1)\} \cup  \{(x, 0) :  0 < x \leq 1 \} \cup \{(1/n, y) : n \in \mathbb N,  0 \leq y \leq 1 \}$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$ with the standard topology.

The definition for connected we use is as follows:

A topological space $X$ is connected if $X$ cannot be written as a union of two non-empty disjoint open sets.

proof:

suppose instead that $X= A \cup B, A \cap B = \emptyset, A,B \neq \emptyset$, and $A, B$ are open relative to $X$.

WLOG let $(0,1) \in A$. $\forall  N$, neighborhood of $(0,1) N \cap \{(1/n, y) : n \in \mathbb N,  0 \leq y \leq 1 \} \neq \emptyset$. For $A$ to be open then $N \subset A$. so $\{(1/n, y) : n \in \mathbb N,  0 \leq y \leq 1 \} \subset A$.

I dont know where to go from here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question is perfectly clear ! The "community robot" has surely been mislead because it didn't find any hair to be combed in the question itself.

Comment: Please use mathja properly. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497792/flea-and-comb-are-connected) thread.
(This had to be a comment but I had not enough reputation.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a general phenomenon at play (as an alternative to the already linked thread [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/497804)):

> Let $X$ be any space, $C$ any connected subspace and $D$ any subspace with $C\subseteq D\subseteq\overline{C}$. Then $D$ is also connected.

We apply this by taking $C$ to be the comb, and $D$ the union of the comb with the 'flea' at $(0,1)$. It is not too hard to see $D$ is contained in the closure of $C$, which may be described as $C\cup\{(0,y):0\le y\le1\}$.

To prove this general theorem, well, I'm sure that's  a duplicate but it doesn't take too long to replicate here. It is equivalent to show continuous functions $f:D\to\{0,1\}$ are constant. In the subspace topology of $D$, we have that $\overline{C}=D$ (recall closure is a relative notion). Recall that we have, just by continuity, $f(\overline{C})\subseteq\overline{f(C)}=f(C)$ (using discreteness of $\{0,1\}$ to say all sets are closed) so $f(D)=f(\overline{C})\subseteq f(C)\subseteq f(D)$ holds, that is, $f(D)=f(C)$ and since $C$ is connected, $f(C)$ is singleton hence $f(D)$ is also singleton i.e. $f$ is constant as desired.

For another example, this theorem gives an easy proof that the topologist's sine curve is connected.

Comment: You probably meant to write $\overline C$ at the end.

Comment: @tomasz I mean, it is also true that $f(D)=f(\overline{C})$. But the most notable fact is that $f(D)=f(C)$ since we know $C$ is connected but don't *yet* know $\overline{C}$ is connected

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I was referring to the statement of the lemma.

Comment: @tomasz aha! Yes, that’s a typo. Thanks